# How does java execute terminal commands?

Tags: java, unix, runtime

Found this to be tricky; Having the following code:

```
String cmd = "find /home/folder/ -type f"; 
Runtime run = Runtime.getRuntime() ; 
Process pr = run.exec(cmd); 
pr.waitFor();
```

I'll `pr.getInputStream()` and have the proper `find` result there, no problem. However, if I want to be a bit more specific and have my command as `cmd = "find /home/folder/ -type f -name somefile*";`, the input stream will be empty.

Now, I thought it would be something related to the string expansions done by the interactive shell (which wouldn't be used in this case, I suppose). In this case the `*` would have no meaning, and `find` would be looking for files really named "*" (something like `\*`). So I've tried to have my command as `sh -c "find /home/folder/ -type f -name somefile*"`. But it didn't work either...

What am I missing?

thanks,

f.

Ps.: It is an AIX box, with IBM's Java JVM.

Comment: Does the find command work as expected from the terminal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I always escape the wildcard when using `find`:

```
cmd = "find /home/folder/ -type f -name somefile\\*";
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be better if you use ProcessBuilder or maybe Runtime.exec methods as they don't need shell escaping and don't run through the shell.

- [ProcessBuilder](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html), is loads more flexible
- [Runtime.exec](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec%28java.lang.String%5b%5d%29), differs from the form that takes only a String